# Git. Syncing local files to new commit after soft reset and commit

Tags: git, reset, checkout

Let's say we have three commits and HEAD pointing to commit C.

```
A-B-(C<--HEAD)
```

I do soft reset on B:

```
$ git reset --soft B
```

Now HEAD is pointing to commit B and commit C is removed

```
A-(B<--HEAD)
```

And index still matches C. So we decide to recommit.

```
$ git commit -m "C again"
$ git log
C'
B
A
```

My question is, since we've done a soft reset local files are not updated. What git command is used to 'sync' local files to the new commit C'? One idea i have is `git checkout C'`.

Another question is after soft reset and committing where does HEAD point to?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you mean with `sync`?. If you run `git checkout C` you would go back to the original revision C and the operation you did with the soft reset and commit would go away.

Comment: make local files have same content as in commit C'

Comment: Well.... the files are already exactly like they were on C if you didn't do anything else besides reset --soft and commit.. Check with `git diff C`. There should be no changes.

Comment: Ok.... I'm starting to understand your point... let me see if I can answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `git reset --soft somewhere` then HEAD points to `somewhere`. If you were working on a branch, then the branch is set to point to that `somewhere` (and HEAD points to the branch). If you were working on detached HEAD, then HEAD is pointed to the revision of the `somewhere` you provided.

Now, about the files.... given that you created the revision straight after doing `git reset --soft` (right?), then the files of C' and C are exactly the same. Check with `git diff C`.

Answer (score -1):

Say after the soft reset we change the content of a file(say file f).

Then if we commit C' I have checked that file f's content does not change with that commit.

Even if we do checkout HEAD, file f's content does not change.

Only thing that changes the content of file f to that of HEAD (ie. C') is if we do a hard reset: `git reset --hard HEAD`.